# extending built-in python dict class

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance, monkeypatching

I want to create a class that would extend dict's functionalities. This is my code so far:

```
class Masks(dict):

    def __init__(self, positive=[], negative=[]):
        self['positive'] = positive
        self['negative'] = negative
```

I want to have two predefined arguments in the constructor: a list of positive and negative masks. When I execute the following code, I can run

```
m = Masks()
```

and a new masks-dictionary object is created - that's fine. But I'd like to be able to create this masks objects just like I can with dicts:

```
d = dict(one=1, two=2)
```

But this fails with Masks:

```
>>> n = Masks(one=1, two=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'two'
```

I should call the parent constructor **init** somewhere in Masks.**init** probably. I tried it with `**kwargs` and passing them into the parent constructor, but still - something went wrong. Could someone point me on what should I add here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/20862

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for this link - it explains default parameter bindings. But I'd also appreciate a hint on what to do with my Masks.__init__ ;)

Comment: Well, that's what kwargs is for.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* call the superclass `__init__` method. And if you want to be able to use the `Masks(one=1, ..)` syntax then you have to use `**kwargs`:

```
In [1]: class Masks(dict):
   ...:     def __init__(self, positive=(), negative=(), **kwargs):
   ...:         super(Masks, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   ...:         self['positive'] = list(positive)
   ...:         self['negative'] = list(negative)
   ...:         

In [2]: m = Masks(one=1, two=2)

In [3]: m['one']
Out[3]: 1
```

---

A general note: **do not subclass built-ins!!!**
It *seems* an easy way to extend them but it has a lot of pitfalls that *will* bite you at some point.

A safer way to extend a built-in is to use delegation, which gives better control on the subclass behaviour and can avoid many pitfalls of inheriting the built-ins. (Note that implementing `__getattr__` it's possible to avoid reimplementing explicitly many methods)

Inheritance should be used as a last resort when you want to pass the object into some code that does explicit `isinstance` checks.

Comment: Be careful when using `or` this way; there may be valid false values that could be passed to it. Consider using a private sentinel object and using `is`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I removed them. I believe a default of `()` and an explicit conversion to `list` is easier to understand(and allows the arguments to be any iterable), even though it has slightly different semantics.

Comment: Subclassing builtins is no more fraught with peril than subclassing anything else, and is frequently quite useful.  The python builtins are well designed to support subclassing, especially `dict`.  Although I'm not convinced that a subclass of dict is necessarily the best option for tdelaney, this sweeping advice is contradictory to my own experiences.  -1.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I don't agree with your statement. In my experience, *every* time I tried to subclass a built-in I discovered that it was much *simpler* and less bug-prone to use delegation(or another, completely different solution to the problem). It's true that the problem isn't the built-ins per se, but inheritance, but this is particularly true with built-ins since they tend to make heavy use of special methods, which can give a lot of surprises if you aren't aware of their exact semantics and how exactly they are called by the interpreter.

Comment: FWIW I _strongly_ agree with @TokenMacGuy, and have found subclassing built-in to be a very useful. It was/is considered by many to be a significant improvement when it was first introduced into Python -- see [Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#subclassing) by Guido van Rossum. Bakuriu, if you've encountered issues subclassing them yourself, perhaps it was due to a limited understanding of how/when to and not to use them on your own part...and not necessarily something that would necessarily apply universally to everyone else.

Answer (score -1):

Since all you want is a regular dict with predefined entries, you can use a factory function.

```
def mask(*args, **kw):
    """Create mask dict using the same signature as dict(),
    defaulting 'positive' and 'negative' to empty lists.
    """
    d = dict(*args, **kw)
    d.setdefault('positive', [])
    d.setdefault('negative', [])
```

Comment: The OP never mentioned that all he wants to do is to provide some default values. He simply stumbled across a problem when writing its subclass. He probably *does* want to add more methods or data in its subclass, and using a function wont work well in that case.

Comment: @Bakuriu hmmm... I must not understand what _I want to have two predefined arguments in the constructor:_ means.

Comment: Can you point out where the OP said that that's the **only** thing that he wants? AFAICT that's only a (pretty useless, since it doesn't add information over the code) comment on the code above, not a formalization of what he meant when saying that he wants to extend `dict`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I want a dict with default entries. And a pony.